# SQL FULLTEXT and AGAINST

Tags: sql, mariadb, against

I'm trying to fulltext search on a MariaDB database but for some reason i'm facing a problem and dont know what else to do.

Imagine you have a database with some data on it.

```
Will Smith En The Graham Norton Show
Steve Smith Departs South Africa Tour In Disgrace
You Take My Breath Away - Rex Smith
Jorja Smith - The One (High Contrast Remix)
```

on a table. and you want to search only the word "Will Smith"

```sql
    SELECT field FROM table AS t1 
    WHERE MATCH (t1.field) AGAINST ('"WILL smith"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But for some reason it returns me all and not just the rows with "Will Smith" on it.. any clue? for other words seems it works ok! but seems there's a problem with the word Will NOT SURE.

Don't say.. use `WHERE LIKE '%Will Smith%'` this is not the question.

Comment: `will` is on the default stopword list according to the MariaDB documentation

Comment: There's a Workaround to this? this sounds non sense to ban words from a search. Will smith is a very simple example that you cannot have stopwords on a search, you can't Ban anyone named Will.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM? or InnoDB?  "Smith" shows up in all rows.

Comment: Can you set the stopword list to an empty list?

Comment: @RickJames i'm trying to figure how disable stopwords list, after that i have to rebuild the table and i'm scared because i wont screw it on the process, MariaDB has no rebuild table.. so not sure how to achieve that task. lot of work and since those stop words are for English and the data is in Spanish is a complete NON SENSE to have (Facepalm)

Comment: @Musikdoktor - If it is InnoDB, `ALTER TABLE tblname ENGINE=InnoDB;` rebuilds the table.

Answer (score 0):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/full-text-index-stopwords/#innodb-stopwords Seems to cover it for InnoDB in MariaDB.